# Changing the date format on the input field instead of the display field

Tags: excel, date, input, excel-formula

I have a large amount of data that needs to be imported into a specialty software from excel. This software only accepts a date format of MM/DD/YYYY. The data I have is formatted in YYYY/MM/DD. This means the software does not accept it.

I expected this could be fixed by changing the date format with right click > format cells, but this operation only changes the way the cell displays the date, not the way the date is written in the input field. I have determined the software pulls the information from the input field, not from how the cell is displayed.

My question is; is there a way to, on a large scale, change how the date is formatted in the cell input without manually retyping it?

Comment: Change date format and export as csv, then the date format will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import a CSV file, then `taller_ExcelHome`'s suggestion in the comment is perfect and simple. Saving as a CSV file will see Excel save the DISPLAYED formatting, so once it is changed to suit, it will give you an import file to use and your original will not see any data change (only the one formatting change).

However, if you must import from your Excel file directly, your basic problem to overcome is that Excel has not recorded the date as the string you see displayed, only as a positive number counting up by days from 1900/0/0 (so 1 = 1900/1/1).

NO formatting of the number will change that, so your Excel file will always have that serial number saved to be imported, and never any formatted display version you see.

There's really only one good approach available, and one could always use a copy of the file as the one to import from of one valued keeping the original unchanged.

You need a column for this, usually called a helper column, and it can be anywhere handy. Often one can just insert a column next to where the data is, but sometimes this has bad effects in formulas that cannot tolerate that. But you can even simply insert an entire sheet, use its column A to do this, and once all done, just delete that extra sheet. No muss, no fuss, as they say.

What you want to do us to get a text version of the dates in the column. You can do this in your helper column with the formula:  (say your dates are in A1:A100)

```
=TEXT(A1:A100,  "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

This takes the serial number Excel has in the cell (it never has your displayed, formatted result), and formats it as the string you use in the function, then does the important step of changing it to a string so it is now truly text, and no longer that serial number that is causing you problems.

You then copy the column of formula results, go back to the original dates, and `Pastee|Special|Values` this data overtop them. You don't even need to change the column's format from your original "YYYY/MM/DD" because Excel sees it as a string now and won't apply that number formatting. As far as it is concerned, the characters are now letters, not numbers.

Delete the helper column. (It is so simple to type out this formula if ever needed again, why make permanent provision for it in your spreadsheet?) Save, and you're ready to import.

If it will come up often (maybe this is a weekly import you need to do), you can make provision for it in any number of ways. Simply using an inserted sheet that has only that purpose is one way, and you could even place such a sheet in an entirely different spreadsheet if, say, you are not to make structural edits. (Very handy, that:  many times you cannot make structural edits to a shared, or "important" spreadsheet. But you can set up a helper spreadsheet, all your own, has sheets with formulas and workspace to do YOUR work, then copy over (carefully!) into the "real" spreadsheet. You must be careful(!) but it can do wonders if you have the discipline to be so.)

If you did the work in the "real" spreadsheet, and now are stuck with a column of strings that look like dates but are hard to get Excel to see as such, and desire to change them back, you can place a "1" in some cell that is preferrably formatted with your desired date format, copy the cell to the Clipboard, then highlight the column of string dates, and `Paste|Special|Multiply` and it will multiply by the 1 so not changing the value, and as part of the order to multiply, it will do its best to consider the cells as numbers, not strings. Fortunately, they are all amenable to that (something like "horsey" can't be `coerced` this way, but anything that reads as a number can) so it will go well. It also applies the cell with the 1's formatting (which is why you wanted to format it with your desired format). Now all is restored for use until the next import.

It all actuall goes easily and quickly. I promise you that even the first time will go faster than reading this took, and after you've done it a time or two, just seconds.